# Excel file corrupted after bulk saving with Python

Tags: python, excel

The aim of my work is just to save multiple Excel Macro files with exactly the same name.
I used the openpyxl library for it. The only thing, which changes in my file is the number att the end.

My code looks as follows:

```
 from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
 wb = load_workbook('Collections/Collection Note - 001.xlsm')
 ws = wb.active
 for x in range(2,25):
    newname = "%03d" % x
    wb.save('Collections/Collection Note - '+newname+'.xlsm')
```

Everything works well as the files come out. However, I have no faintest idea why are they corrupted?

What is wrong here, since I want just open them and resave?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are using xlsm files (files with Macro-enable).

In this case youve to load the files differently:

```
load_workbook('Collections/Collection Note - 001.xlsm', read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
```

(Btw you could look inside your xlsm files by renaming them to filename.zip and check if there is stuff missing)